# Flutter web build cant run gif on firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

the gif work on my website locally but when i `flutter build web` and deploy it on my firebase hosting the gif didn't appear. someone know why?

I am using this.

```
    Image.asset(
       "magic.gif",
       height: 250.0,
       width: 250.0,
   ),


  assets:
   - assets/magic.gif
```

[image]

Comment: you're likely to have some kind of CORS issues. Are you doing Image.network? Or getting that image from http get method?

Comment: nope. its inside the folder.

Answer (score 0):

i solved it. need to include the folder name "assets".

```
    Image.asset(
       "assets/magic.gif",
       height: 250.0,
       width: 250.0,
   ),
```